# Why my pdf created with Apache PdfBox doesn't integrate new lines?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to create a multiple line pdf document.
I'm using PdfBox from Apache.

I had this simple code :

```
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        // Retrieving the pages of the document
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);

        contentStream.showText("blabla");
        contentStream.newLine(); 
        contentStream.showText("blabla");
        contentStream.newLine(); 
        contentStream.showText("blabla");
        contentStream.newLine();
```

And I get only a simple line like this :
"blablablablablabla"

Can somebody help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: You don't set the leading. Thus, the blablas should overwrite each other and not follow each other.

Comment: @jozinho22 if the answer was helpful (I think it is), please click the checkmark to make it the accepted answer. If it didn't help, please tell in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've forgotten to use setLeading? Before using `contentStream.newLine()` you need to use `contentStream.setLeading(float)`

(main source here: https://www.javatpoint.com/pdfbox-adding-multiple-lines)

I've edited the relevant part of your code:

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(20,600); // set starting position
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);

contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);  // set the size of the newline to something reasonable

contentStream.showText("blabla");
contentStream.newLine();
contentStream.showText("blabla");
contentStream.newLine();
contentStream.showText("blabla");
contentStream.newLine();
```

Running this on my machine makes multiple lines, so long as the rest of the code works (closing and opening the file correctly).